# Error while creating an app with primary language in app store

Tags: localization, app-store

While creating an app in app store with primary language as English (US), it says "The app name you entered is already being used". However, when I change Primary language to something else like English (Canada), it goes through successfully.

I got to know that, more than one app with same app names is not allowed in a country. So, can I know how this works? Looking at the above example, If I create an app with English (Canada) as a primary language, would that make my app invisible in US?

Answer (score 0):

No your app will be visible in US, but I do not recommend doing that.

My recommendation: Change your app name a little bit just to be approved in US.

Note: Make sure that the name you are using is not copyrighted to someone else, because they can remove it from App Store if they have a copyright of the name or a part of it.